# IWebBrowser2.Navigate2 fails to INET_E_RESOURCE_NOT_FOUND (0x800C0005) during a new session

Tags: windows, atl, ole, iwebbrowser2

In my ATL project I have the window which is a host for html browser.
I have a need to create/destroy this window during runtime.
When `IWebBrowser2.Navigate2` is called third time it triggers `DISPID_NAVIGATEERROR` with the status `INET_E_RESOURCE_NOT_FOUND (0x800C0005)`. MSDN describes it as the server or proxy was not found but I call the method for exactly the same URL as in previous sessions.

I do the following in my code:

Init routine:

```
ole_obj_.CoCreateInstance(CLSID_WebBrowser);
ole_obj_->SetClientSite(this);
ole_obj_->DoVerb(OLEIVERB_SHOW, NULL, site, 0, GetHWND(), &rect);
CComQIPtr<IWebBrowser2> webBrowser(ole_obj_);
DispEventAdvise(webBrowser, &DIID_DWebBrowserEvents2);
```

Navigate routine:

```
CComQIPtr<IWebBrowser2> webBrowser(ole_obj_);
webBrowser->Navigate2(&varUrl, 0, 0, 0, 0);
```

Destroy routine:

```
DispEventUnadvise(ole_obj_, &DIID_DWebBrowserEvents2);
ole_obj_->Close(OLECLOSE_NOSAVE);
ole_obj_.Release();
```

The interesting fact that if I comment `ole_obj_->Close(OLECLOSE_NOSAVE);` it works but of course I get a memory leak.

Any advice is welcome.

Comment: 1. You `Advise` on the `webBrowser` but `Unadvise` on the on the `ole_obj_`. 2. Do ATL smart COM pointers throw exceptions? If not, are you checking all returned error codes?